# Complicated loop of queries into a single one

Tags: mysql

I need a little bit of help with making a complicated query, i will try to explain what i am trying to accomplish down below.

Here is my data

table_one

```
+---------+---------+----------+----------+
| user_id | poly_id |    in    |   out    |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|     900 |       1 | 20-12-17 | 20-12-17 |
|     900 |       2 | 21-12-17 | 22-12-17 |
|     900 |       3 | 22-12-17 | 24-12-17 |
|     900 |       1 | 23-12-17 | 26-12-17 |
|     444 |       4 | 24-12-17 | 28-12-17 |
|     444 |       4 | 25-12-17 | 30-12-17 |
|     444 |       5 | 26-12-17 | 01-01-18 |
|     444 |       3 | 27-12-17 | 03-01-18 |
|     900 |       2 | 28-12-17 | 05-01-18 |
|     900 |       1 | 29-12-17 | 07-01-18 |
|     444 |       2 | 30-12-17 | 09-01-18 |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

table_two

```
+----+---------+-------------+---------+
| id |  name   |    type     | product |
+----+---------+-------------+---------+
|  1 | city 1  | gas station | general |
|  2 | city 2  | workshop    | general |
|  3 | city 3  | paint       | bikes   |
|  4 | city 4  | paint       | general |
|  5 | city 5  | gas station | cars    |
|  6 | city 6  | gas station | bikes   |
|  7 | city 7  | paint       | cars    |
|  8 | city 8  | workshop    | cars    |
|  9 | city 9  | gas station | general |
| 10 | city 10 | gas station | cars    |
| 11 | city 11 | gas station | general |
+----+---------+-------------+---------+
```

i have a working solution that looks like this

```
//results comes from somewhere else, it looks something like this for example:
array (
    "user_id" => "poly_id of the last gas station"
    "900" => 1,
    "444" => 10 
)
foreach ($result AS $res ) {

    $query = "

        SELECT 
                    table_one.name AS name
        FROM 
                    `table_one`
                LEFT JOIN 
                    `table_two` ON table_one.poly_id = table_two.id
                WHERE 
                    `table_two`.type = 'gas station '
                AND 
                    table_one.user_id = $res['user_id']
                AND 
                    table_one.poly_id != $res['poly_id']
                AND 
                    table_one.in >= "some date from'
                AND 
                    table_one.out <= 'some date to'
                AND 
                    (FIND_IN_SET('general', table_two.product) > 0  OR FIND_IN_SET('cars', table_two.product) > 0 )

                ORDER BY out DESC LIMIT 1

    ";

    //if the results is not empty use the result['name']
}
```

The idea is: I have the user last gas station, but i need to find the previous one between a date range.

As i said, the above example is working just fine, however i need to be able to process multiple results at once, and sometimes the results are ~2000.
Which means 2000+ queries per request.

1. Is it even possible to somehow optimize this loop of queries into a single one, so I don't do 2000 queries per request ?
2. If possible, how :D

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return result contains user_id with it's last
enter in the given periode.

one thing here because you are
using date not date time if the user exit in the same
day two time you will have two record of that user you can skip the second
record in you code

```sql
 select 
   user_id,
   in,
   out
   from table_one t1
   INNER JOIN ( 
       select 
         user_id
         max(out) as 'max_out',
       from
          table_one
       where 
         in >= ? AND
         out <= ? AND
         ploy_id not in [list_of_unwanted_ploy_id]
         -- you can specify any condition here 
       group by user_id
   ) l_out on t1.user_id = l_out.user_id and t1.out = l_out.max_out
where 
   t1.user_id in [list_of_user_id]
```

Comment: its actually timestamp in the databases, because its super complicated question i was trying to make it simpler for the question itself

Comment: then you will never have two record having the same`out` value so you will never have two user_id in the result

Comment: insanely good man, Thanks a lot. I need a little bit of time to test it out. Once I got it i will let you know. But on first sights it looks awesome. Thanks !

Comment: i had use this type of query a lot of time hope it help you ^^

Comment: unfortunately  1 think is missing and its the poly_id that i need to be different. In english: i need the last gas station, but not the one I have the $results array. Hopefully you can understand.

Comment: i hope i understood what you said lol. check my updates you can put you condition in both where clause to specify what you need exactly.